# feature selection and random forest

Tags: machine-learning

I did some research in WEKA. and try to predict something using five different machine learning algorithms. the accuracy was around 85.
after doing feature selection, the accuracy increase a little, but only the accuracy of the random forest algorithm decrease from 86 to 81.
do someone know or can think why is that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Random Forest is essentially a bagging (bootstrap aggregating) method and it is therefore most useful in high variance regimes. It could be the case that you do not have a high variance problem. Especially since it seems that feature selection helps with your accuracy, you might have a high bias problem. In this case, random forest's performance will decrease.